# MySql Tag System - How to select just one Tag for each Id, without repeating the same Tag?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm implementing a Tag system using PHP and MySql.

In my Tags table there are two columns (Id and Tag).
Each Id may have one or more tag(s) associated to it - like this:

| Id | Tag |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | red |
| 1 | blue |
| 1 | orange |
| 2 | green |
| 3 | black |
| 4 | grey |
| 5 | grey |
| 6 | pink |
| 7 | white |
| 7 | purple |
| 8 | blue |
| 9 | yellow |
| 9 | cyan |

Now I need to show, in descending order, just one Tag for each Id, without repeating the same Tag - like this:

| Id | Tag |
| --- | --- |
| 9 | yellow |
| 8 | blue |
| 7 | white |
| 6 | pink |
| 5 | grey |
| 3 | black |
| 2 | green |
| 1 | red |

(here the Id is not relevant: i.e. it's not important that "grey" Tag belongs to "5" or to "4" Id).

I've tried the following two queries:

```
SELECT * FROM Tags GROUP BY Id ORDER BY Id DESC
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Tags ORDER BY Id DESC
```

But none of them produces what I want to achieve.

I've been searching a lot for a solution on the web (I'm new to MySql), but couldn't find anything useful.

Would you give me any suggestions?

Comment: What if there are 2 ids with only 1 and the same tag?

Comment: @forpas In that case, the query should return that tag just once. The id makes no difference.

Comment: If 2 tags belong to only 1 Id then only 1 of them will be in the results, right?

Comment: @forpas An example (Id/Tag): 1/[only] red; 3/[only] red. Then "red" should be returned just once. Does my question raise doubts?

Comment: I'm not asking about that. I see in your sample data that red and orange belong only to id=1. This means that in the results will be only 1 of red and orange. So there are tags in the sample data that won't be in the results. Is that right?

Comment: Do you need to find a best solution, or just any? (e.g. "1=red, 2=yellow, 3=yellow, 3=red, 3=blue" has exactly one solution (the one where 3 is blue) that includes all 3 tags). If you need a best solution: do you have any constraints for your tags which would limit the search space (e.g. only a maximum number of tags or ids)?

Comment: Query will be always limited to the last 20 rows inserted in the table. If an Id has more than one Tag associated to it, I need to get the first Tag only (in my example: 1:red, 7: white, 9:yellow), ignoring other Tags having same Id. After that, I need to remove duplicate Tags. This is what I had in mind. But I'm open to other solutions, if you think that a different approach would be better. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NOT EXISTS` to filter out duplicate tags and aggregate:

```
SELECT t1.Id, MAX(t1.Tag) Tag  
FROM Tags t1 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
 SELECT 1
 FROM Tags t2
 WHERE t2.Id > t1.Id AND t2.Tag = t1.Tag
)
GROUP BY t1.Id
ORDER BY t1.Id DESC
```

Instead of `MAX()` you could use `MIN()` or [`ANY_VALUE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_any-value).

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d93bac5b2df25c549a246e207d2b3f0f).

Comment: I get a syntax error. Maybe the first line should be `SELECT t1.Id, MAX(Tag) Tag` like in the demo.

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner MAX(Tag) Tag is the same as MAX(t1.Tag) Tag in this case but I prefer MAX(t1.Tag) Tag so I edited the demo. What is the syntax error? The demo is working fine.

Comment: I get this error: "PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT t1.Id, MAX(t1.Tag) Tag FROM Tags t1 WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 ' at line 2 in...". I need to change the first line as I said above to make it work (MySql version: 5.7). Your demo works perfectly.

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner do you have any sql code before this query? The error message mentions the start of the query as problematic which is not possible.

Comment: There's no any sql code before the query. The problem is the first query line: in fact, if I change it in `SELECT t1.Id, MAX(Tag) Tag` it works fine. I've just tried it again. Don't know why.

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner Where do you execute this query?

Comment: It's a PHP file running on Windows Server 2019 (if you mean that).

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner so you don't execute the query directly. It's not possible for the alias `t1` to cause an error for `MAX(t1.Tag)` and not for `t1.Id`. Check your PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

Create a temp table with unique constraint and do insert ignore.

```
DROP Temporary table IF exists T_Test;
create Temporary table T_Test(id INTEGER UNIQUE, tag VARCHAR(10) UNIQUE);
insert IGNORE into T_Test
SELECT * FROM Tags
ORDER BY id DESC,  tag DESC;

SELECT * from T_Test;
```